# Adding a periodic timeout to select from a sub-class of Net::Server::HTTP

Tags: perl, server

I'm trying to write a small service that responds to a couple commands (to check/report on status), but every 15 seconds or so breaks out of its polling status to check a database for messages and fork off a child to do some processing.

I'm sub-classing Net::Server::HTTP, for example:

```
my $service = MyService->new("port" => 8080);
$service->run(app => {
    "/ping" => sub { print_client("Pong"); },
    "/status" => sub { print_client("Good, thanks"); },
});
```

but I can't figure out how to get a timeout through the class hierarchy to reach the socket's select call. I was hoping I could pass a timeout through, or use a while(1) with an alarm to break out of the run method, but neither is working.

What I was /hoping/ for was to do:

```
while (1) {
    $service->run(
        timeout => 15,
        app => { ... }
    });

    check_database();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this while keeping the code simple?